# Is it possible to resolve merge conflicts in GitHub's web interface

Tags: git, github, git-merge

Is it possible to resolve and merge a git conflict in GitHub's web interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of December 2016, [simple merge conflicts can be resolved in GitHub's web interface](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/).

> 1. Under your repository name, click **Pull requests**.
>
> [image: Pull Requests tab]
>
> 2. In the "Pull Requests" list, click the pull request with a merge conflict that you'd like to resolve.
> 3. Near the bottom of your pull request, click **Resolve conflicts**.
>
>    - (Tip: If the Resolve conflicts button is deactivated, your pull request's merge conflict is too complex to resolve on GitHub and you
>        must resolve the merge conflict on the command line.)
>
> [image: Resolve conflicts button]
>
> 4. Decide if you want to keep only your branch's changes, keep only the other branch's changes, or make a brand new change, which may
>      incorporate changes from both branches. Delete the conflict markers
>      `<<<<<<<`, `=======`, `>>>>>>>` and make the changes you want in the
>      final merge.
>
> [image: Resolving conflicts]
>
> 5. If you have more than one merge conflict in your file, scroll down to the next set of conflict markers and repeat steps four and five to
>      resolve your merge conflict.
> 6. Once you've resolved all the conflicts in the file, click **Mark as resolved**.
>
> [image: Mark as resolved]
>
> 7. If you have more than one file with a conflict, select the next file you want to edit on the left side of the page under "conflicting
>      files" and repeat steps four through seven until you've resolved all
>      of your pull request's merge conflicts.
>
> [image: Select a file]
>
> 8. Once you've resolved all your merge conflicts, click **Commit changes**.
>
> [image: Commit changes]
>
> 9. To merge your pull request, click **Merge pull request**. For more information about other pull request merge options, see "Merging a pull request."

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: the ability to resolve simple merge conflicts in GitHub was released last month (Dec 2016).

If a merge conflict has occurred because there’s a difference on the same line of the same file between the two different branches of your pull request, you can now hit the **Resolve conflicts** button in the body of the pull request to edit the text. All other types of merge conflicts must be resolved locally on the command line.

GitHub Documentation: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/

Answer (score 1):

The Github website does not provide an interface to deal with merge conflicts I'm afraid. You will need to pull the branches to a local machine with git and resolve the conflict from there.

Comment: As of December 2016 [simple merge conflicts can be solved directly on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github/).

Answer (score 1):

This method is for those who don't want to use [GitHub's web interface](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/addressing-merge-conflicts/resolving-a-merge-conflict-on-github) for conflict in multiple files. It works with every repo storage provider.

### Steps to follow

**1.** Suppose we have to merge branch DEV -> to ->  STAGE.

**2.** First don't push any changes to the DEV branch and save it locally.

> **If the commit has been pushed to the DEV branch, you can revert those changes as they were before, by simply pushing new commit with old changes to DEV branch.**

**3.** Create a new pull request and merge STAGE -> to -> DEV branch.

> **If you encounter conflicts in this step, you have made some mistake in the above step 2.**

**4.** After the merge (STAGE -> DEV) process is complete, commit your changes to the DEV branch that were saved locally.

**5.** Now create a new pull request DEV -> to ->  STAGE and your conflicts will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

When you are resolving conflicts on the command line normally, you are using a **bash** shell on Mac or something like **Git Bash** on Windows.  In your web browser, you have a **JavaScript** command line, which can't emulate your bash shell.

**Pretty much, you can't solve conflicts in the online JS shell.**